# Sum and intersection of annihilators.

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I am a beginner in this course,  please give me a detailed step by step solution of this problem.

Let $W_1$ and $W_2$ be subspaces of a finite dimensional vector space $V$. If $X$ is a subspace of $V$ , I use the notation $X^0$ to denote the set of linear functionals $f$ on $V$ that *annihilate* $X$. We have the following to prove:
$$(W_1 + W_2)^0 = W_1^0\cap W_2^0 $$

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: @Kevin Quirin : I an a beginner, I have got an intuition, but am not being able to write down things logically. I need help in writing down things..

Comment: You should write out what those things actually mean from the definition of annihilator